Face Recognize From the Database using embedding technique
I am working on a project aimed at recognizing whether a photo of any individual exists in the university's records. The proposed method involves storing the embeddings of each student's photo, along with their details, in a vector database. When a photo needs to be compared, the system will generate the embedding value for that photo and then compare this value against the database. If the value falls within a specific threshold, it will indicate that the individual exists in the record.
I am seeking expert advice on whether this approach is feasible. If there are any concerns with this method, I would appreciate recommendations for the best solution.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Hey, Muhammad, you've got even two answers on your question. Normally, you'd react somehow....

Firstly, find vector embeddings of your facial database.
from deepface import DeepFace

students = ["alice.jpg", "bob.jpg", "charlie.jpg"]

for student in students:
   embedding = DeepFace.represent(img_path = student)[0]["embedding"]
   # store student and embedding in your database

Herein, the querying approach will be different according to the vector database you adopted. If you prefer to use postgres with pgvector extension.
# real-time taken photo
target_img = "target.jpg"
target_embedding = DeepFace.represent(img_path = target_img)[0]["embedding"]

query = f"""
     SELECT *
     FROM (
         SELECT i.img_name, embedding <-> '{str(target_embedding)}' as distance
         FROM embeddings_datastore i
     ) a
     WHERE distance < {threshold}
     ORDER BY distance asc
"""

the trick is to determine the correct threshold. the default facial recognition model in deepface is vgg-face. its pre-tuned threshold is 1.17 for euclidean distance as mentione here. so, the query will discard items with higher distance.
you can also adopt vector indexes such as annoy, voyager, faiss, nmslib or elasticsearch instead of a vector database. querying will be different according to your design but the idea will be same.
also, if the number of items in your database is not too big (~hundreds), then you may not need to use either vector index or vector database. postgres without pgvector extension, mongo, redis, cassandra or any relational database even sqlite would be fine.

Yes, you've chosen the right approach.  My advice is to use Elasticsearch (built-in) capabilities to store huge data as well as to extremely fast compare long vectors.
I'm normally using Insightface for all face recognition tasks, so Elasticsearch docs have the following mapping:
mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "face_id": {
            "type": "keyword"
            },
        "face_vector":{
            "type": "dense_vector",
            "dims": 512,
            "index": "true",
            "similarity": "l2_norm"
            },
        "pic_file_path": {
            "type": "text",
            "index": "false"
            },
        "face_location": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": "false"
            },
        "kps": {
            "type": "integer",
            "index": "false"
            },
        "gender": {
            "type": "byte"
            },
        "description": {
            "type": "text"
            },
        "descr_length": {
            "type": "integer"
            }
        }
    }

}

The mapping will also allow to use extra fast KNN-search among millions of the students faces :)
